# Modal not appearing in Javascript, Using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make modal appear when I click on sign up. But the problem is that The modal is not appearing although I have checked the code many times. The modal code when just used without the other content works just fine. The source code is from W3Schools. I am sorry in advance for the way this code occurs, but How stackoverflow text editor works is beyond me. I am new to this,so please don't fry me if it's an idiotic mistake

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="demo.htm.appcache">
<head>
<link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image.ico" href="Airbnb logo.ico">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-

bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <style>
      @keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
      </style>  
    </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar">
        <ul class ="nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li> 
          <li class="pull-right active"><a href="Airbnb.html">Homepage</a></li>     
          <li class="pull-right">
              <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign Up</a>  <!-- Modal is declared here -->
            </li>
          <li class="pull-right"><a href="Log%20in.htm" >Log In</a></li>
          <li class="pull-right"><a href="Help.htm" >Help</a></li>
        </ul>
          </div>
          </div>






    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Find a place to stay.</h1>
        <p>Rent from people in over 34,000 cities and 192 countries.</p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="neighborhood-guides">
            <h2>Neighbourhood Guides</h2>
            <p>Not sure where to stay? We've created neighbourood guides for cities all around the world</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class ="col-md-4">        
                <div class ="thumbnail">
                <div class="zoom">
                <img src ="http://goo.gl/0sX3jq" class = "growImage" width="100px">
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="thumbnail">
                <div class="zoom">
                <img src ="http://goo.gl/an2HXY" class="growImage">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="col-md-4">          
                <div class ="thumbnail">
                    <div class="zoom">
                    <img src = "http://goo.gl/Av1pac" class="growImage">
                </div>
                    </div>
                <div class ="thumbnail">
                    <div class="zoom">
                    <img src ="http://goo.gl/vw43v1" class="growImage">
                </div>    
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="col-md-4">    
                <div class ="thumbnail">
                    <div class="zoom">
                <img src ="http://goo.gl/0Kd7UO">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="learn-more">
      <div class="container">

        <div class ="row">
          <div class= "col-md-4">
            <h3>Travel</h3>
            <p>From apartments and rooms to treehouses and boats: stay in unique spaces in 192 countries.</p>
            <p><a href="#">See how to travel on Airbnb</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Host</h3>
            <p>Renting out your unused space could pay your bills or fund your next vacation.</p>
            <p><a href="#">Learn more about hosting</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class ="col-md-4">
            <h3>Trust and Safety</h3>
            <p>From Verified ID to our worldwide customer support team, we've got your back.</p>
            <p><a href="#">Learn about trust at Airbnb</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class ="container">
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


      <script type="text/javascript">    

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.zoom').mouseover(function(){
      //moving the div left a bit is completely optional
      //but should have the effect of growing the image from the middle.
      $(this).stop().animate({"width": "110%","left":"0px","top":"0px"}, 400,'swing');
    }).mouseout(function(){ 
      $(this).stop().animate({"width": "95%","left":"15px","top":"15px"}, 200,'swing');
    });;
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just a quick side note... I grabbed your code and reformatted it. It is best to remove spacing from all file names. so your login page and your icon need to be renamed. I do not think this will fix your issue, but it may help with other issues in the future.

Comment: @ph33nyx Ok and I'll take care of this in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 3.x requires jQuery 1.9.x or higher.

Your reference points to jQuery 1.3.2, which will not work with Bootstrap.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Feel free to accept my answer
 if you feel it was useful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

starting over...
I used Chrome to test it, and could not make it work with a link or a button. But when I checked the console I see that there is a javascript error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND bootstrap.js:15
>   Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1
>   or higher

I got it to work by upgrading to jquery 1.10.2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you look in the navibar div you'll find modal. It's also in the comments in code